# Ruby on Rails: New post not saving on the blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working on an exercise, creating a blog with ruby on rails. I have the form ready to post an article, but once I click on the submit button, I am redirected to the homepage but the article doesn't save. Here is the following code

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page], per_page: 5).order('created_at DESC')
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(title: params.permit[:title], body: params.permit[:body])

    if @article.save
      redirect_to articles, :notice => "Your post has been saved"
    else
      render :create
    end
  end

end
```

Here is the view create.html.haml

```
.container
    .row
        .col-xs-9-
            .panel-title
                %h2 Ecrivez votre article
                = form_for @article do |f|
                    = f.text_field :title
                    = f.text_area :body, size: "60x12"
                    = f.submit "Publier"
```

Then the route.rb, I don't know if it can help

```
TP2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles, only: [:index]

  get 'articles' => 'articles#index'

  get 'articles/:id' => 'articles#show'

  get 'articles/new'

  get 'post' => 'articles#create'

  post 'articles' => 'articles#index'
```

And to finish here is what the console show when I try to post an article

```
Started GET "/post" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-10 14:24:56 +0200
Processing by ArticlesController#create as HTML
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendered articles/create.html.haml within layouts/application (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 4.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)


Started POST "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-10 14:25:10 +0200
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"FMQmKvZ1t98ZE21VaiBQhm0jKJ9x9BwkXFbh4obfi3Qea0Zax5dgGirfpgcAiQA464GMD2+Qv/eGYrmvEoTZBQ==", "article"=>{"title"=>"Post", "body"=>"New Article test"}, "commit"=>"Publier"}
  Article Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles"  ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "articles"
  Rendered articles/index.html.haml within layouts/application (3.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 5.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

I don't understand why the new article won't save. Does anyone understand why ?

Comment: use `@article.save!` it throws an exception so you can debug

Comment: Your routes are messy too. You `post` on index your should get index and post for create. Use resources :articles instead. Another point is that you should use the benefits of strong params. I'll post an answer to guide you.

Comment: Can you link the tutorial or the book where you find your exercise ?

Comment: Start a rails console in the terminal and then create a  new article, save it and call errors on it to see why its failing. Is it failing some validation or attribute restriction?

Comment: I think the params your using are not good you should use something like params[:article][:title] because your using an Article object in your form so you will get the params as an hash like params: {article: {title: "my_title", body:"my_body"}}

Comment: In your logs we see that your posting your "new article params" in the index action. We see the params there. So your routes are not good and the create action is not working. See my answer if needed.

Comment: I don't know who is down voting this question but I would be curious to know why? This is the first question of @john_ee on stack and the question is well asked. Don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'articles#index' # or where you want for the first page

  resources :articles #will give you the correct path and verbs
end
```

And the articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

 ...

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to @article, notice: "Article created!" }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: I corrected my code with yours and it worked. I had to modify some stuff to, such as my new article page was called create.html.haml and I renamed it new.html.haml. You were asking about the tutorial but it's an exercise I'm working on in college. Also, I wasn't comfortable with the routes, thing is I feel like Ruby on Raisl does everything for you.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Ok, no problem for the tutorial. I think that when you get the global idea behind "rails magic" you can start to stop using it (like resources) and start to use more specific strategies. Your problem was mostly linked to the fact that the wrong verb (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) was used on the wrong path. I think this guide can help to clear this out: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Because you are learning new stuff, this is a way you should use to debug your code:

- put a `binding.pry` (a breakpoint) on the line before `@article.save` (or use another debugger, you can find it on Github)
- reload your page, input the fields and click Save
- go to the rails console, issue `@article.save` on the console (or `@article.valid?`), it should return false
- `puts @article.errors`, so you can what are the validation issues

Good luck :)

Comment: I'll check this out. The other answer helped out but thanks for the advice.